# When I use global variables it crashes my kernel

Tags: gcc, x86-64, bootloader, osdev, linker-scripts

I have had this happen before and worked around it for a while but now it slowly becomes more and more unavoidable, because now I need them.
For some weird reason, my kernel crashes when I try to use a global variable in my code.

This works:

```
int global;

void kmain()
{
    //do some stuff...
}
```

This does not work:

```
int global;

void kmain()
{
    global = 1;
    
    //do some stuff...
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening.
As some additional resources here is my linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)

phys = 0x0500;

SECTIONS
{
    .text phys : AT(phys) {
        code = .;
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .data : AT(phys + (data - code))
    {
        data = .;
        *(.data)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .bss : AT(phys + (bss - code)) {
        bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    end = .;

    /DISCARD/
     : {
        *(.comment)
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.note.gnu.build-id)
    }
}
```

and my makefile:

```
bin/UmbrellaOS.img: bin/boot.bin bin/kernel.bin bin/zeros.bin
    cat $^ > $@

bin/kernel.bin: tmp/kernel_entry.o tmp/kernel.o
    x86_64-elf-ld -o $@ -T link.ld $^

tmp/kernel.o: src/kernel/main.c
    x86_64-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -m64 -g -c $^ -o $@
```

Edit:
To be more specific I use QEMU to test my OS upon starting QEMU it instantly closes. It should also be noted that if I try something like this:

```
int global;

void kmain()
{
    return;
    global = 0;
}
```

it works for some reason.
I can see a green L printed to the screen which is the last thing my bootloader does before passing control to the kernel after long mode has been entered.

btw here is my bootloader:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7C00]

KERNEL_LOC equ 0x0500

_start:
    mov [_BootDisk], dl
    
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax

    mov bp, 0x7BFF
    mov sp, bp

    push 0x7E00         ; buffer
    push 1              ; sectors to read
    push 2              ; sector num
    call DiskRead
    jc .error

    push ebx
    pushfd
    pop eax
    mov ebx, eax
    xor eax, 0x200000
    push eax
    popfd
    pushfd
    pop eax
    cmp eax, ebx
    jnz .supported
    push _CpuErrorString
    call Print
    jmp .error
    .supported:

    mov eax, 0x80000000
    cpuid
    cmp eax, 0x80000001
    jb .no64
    mov eax, 0x80000001
    cpuid
    test edx, 1 << 29
    jnz .is64
    .no64:
    push _64ErrorString
    call Print
    jmp .error
    .is64:
    
    push 0x8000
    call MapMem
    
    push KERNEL_LOC     ; buffer
    push 8              ; sectors to read
    push 3              ; sector num
    call DiskRead
    jc .error
    
    cli
    lgdt [GDT_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:protected_mode

    .error:
    jmp $

Print:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov bx, [bp+4]
    mov ah, 0x0E
    .loop:
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp al, 0
    je .end
    int 0x10
    inc bx
    jmp .loop
    .end:
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret 2

DiskRead:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, [bp+6]
    mov ch, 0
    mov cl, [bp+4]
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, [_BootDisk]
    mov bx, [bp+8]
    int 0x13
    cmp al, [bp+6]
    je .end
    jnc .end
    push _DiskErrorString
    call Print
    .end:
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret 6

MapMem:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov si, [bp+4]
    mov di, [bp+4]
    add di, 4
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150
    mov eax, 0xE820
    mov [di+20], dword 1
    mov ecx, 24
    int 0x15
    jc .failed

    mov edx, 0x0534D4150
    cmp eax, edx
    jne .failed
    test ebx, ebx
    je .failed

    .loop:
        mov eax, 0xE820
        mov [di+20], dword 1
        mov ecx, 24
        int 0x15
        jc .finish
        mov edx, 0x0534D4150

        .jmpin:
        jcxz .skip
        cmp cl, 20
        jbe .notext
        test byte [di+20], 1
        je .skip
        
        .notext:
        mov ecx, [di+8]
        or ecx, [di+12]
        jz .skip
        inc dword [si]
        add di, 24
        
        .skip:
        test ebx, ebx
        jne .loop
        
        .finish:
        clc
        jmp .end
    .failed:
    push _MemErrorString
    call Print
    stc
    jmp .end
    .end:
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret 2

_BootDisk: db 0
_DiskErrorString: db "Disk read error!", 13, 10, 0
_MemErrorString: db "Memory mapping failed!", 13, 10, 0
_CpuErrorString: db "CPUID not supported!", 13, 10, 0
_64ErrorString: db "x64 bits not supported!", 13, 10, 0

CODE_SEG equ GDT_code - GDT_start
DATA_SEG equ GDT_data - GDT_start

GDT_start:
    GDT_null:
        dd 0x0
        dd 0x0
    GDT_code:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10011010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
    GDT_data:
        dw 0xffff
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 0b10010010
        db 0b11001111
        db 0x0
GDT_end:

GDT_descriptor:
    dw GDT_end - GDT_start - 1
    dd GDT_start

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

[bits 32]
protected_mode:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    call Clear
    
    mov ebx, VGA_MEM
    mov byte [ebx], 'P'
    inc ebx
    mov byte [ebx], 14

    mov eax, cr0
    and eax, ~(1 << 31)
    mov cr0, eax

    mov edi, 0x1000
    mov cr3, edi
    xor eax, eax
    mov ecx, 4096
    rep stosd
    mov edi, cr3

    mov dword [edi], 0x2003
    add edi, 0x1000
    mov dword [edi], 0x3003
    add edi, 0x1000
    mov dword [edi], 0x4003
    add edi, 0x1000
    mov ebx, 0x00000003
    mov ecx, 512

    .set_entry:
    mov dword [edi], ebx
    add ebx, 0x1000
    add edi, 8
    loop .set_entry

    mov eax, cr4
    or eax, 1 << 5
    mov cr4, eax

    mov ecx, 0xC0000080
    rdmsr
    or eax, 1 << 8
    wrmsr

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1 << 31
    mov cr0, eax

    lgdt [GDT.Pointer]
    jmp GDT.Code:long_mode

    jmp $

Clear:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ecx, VGA_SIZE
    mov eax, VGA_MEM
    .loop:
    mov byte [eax], 0
    inc eax
    loop .loop
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

PRESENT         equ 1 << 7
NOT_SYS         equ 1 << 4
EXEC            equ 1 << 3
RW              equ 1 << 1
ACCESSED        equ 1 << 0

GRAN_4K         equ 1 << 7
SZ_32           equ 1 << 6
LONG_MODE       equ 1 << 5

GDT:
    .Null: equ $ - GDT
        dq 0
    .Code: equ $ - GDT
        dd 0xFFFF
        db 0
        db PRESENT | NOT_SYS | EXEC | RW
        db GRAN_4K | LONG_MODE | 0xF
        db 0
    .Data: equ $ - GDT
        dd 0xFFFF
        db 0
        db PRESENT | NOT_SYS | RW
        db GRAN_4K | SZ_32 | 0xF
        db 0
    .TSS: equ $ - GDT
        dd 0x00000068
        dd 0x00CF8900
    .Pointer:
        dw $ - GDT - 1
        dq GDT

[bits 64]
long_mode:
    cli
    mov ax, GDT.Data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    
    mov rbp, 0x0007FFFF
    mov rsp, rbp

    mov rbx, VGA_MEM
    mov byte [rbx], 'L'
    inc rbx
    mov byte [rbx], 2

    jmp KERNEL_LOC

VGA_MEM equ 0xB8000
VGA_WIDTH equ 80
VGA_HEIGHT equ 25
VGA_STRIDE equ 2
VGA_SIZE equ VGA_WIDTH * VGA_STRIDE * VGA_HEIGHT
VGA_LENGTH equ VGA_WIDTH * VGA_HEIGHT

times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

And for anyone wanting to see the big picture here's the [Github repository](https://github.com/teutinsa/UmbrellaOS) I made.

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Comment: But some things to check: (1) are you sure your loader successfully loaded the entire kernel, including the data section?  (2) if you're now in long mode, are you sure the region corresponding to the data section has been mapped read/write?

Comment: (3) are you sure you actually *did* switch to long mode?  If not, the code might run for a bit anyway, due to the machine code being similar in both modes.  But memory access is likely to break it, when your pointers are the wrong size.

Comment: Is that memory RW?

Comment: Looking at your bootloader you read 8 sectors of 512 bytes each for a total of 4KiB for the kernel but your linker script seems to be using alignment of 4KiB so I think its possible your kernel may be larger than you are reading. How large is your kernel.bin? If it's greater than 4KiB then that'll be a problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge : In a previous answer we determined he was getting into long mode (just at the time he was building as 32-bit code and running it in long mode which of course didn't work as expected)

Comment: @MichaelPetch on disk my kernel.bin currently has a size of 3Kb.

Comment: @FlorianSchumacher; So I guess the `.data` section must be empty, and your variable `global` is being put in `.bss`, which would make sense.  Since `.bss` isn't loaded from your binary, it is your loader's responsibility to figure out how many additional pages are needed, map them read/write, and zero them.  Let's see the code where you do that.

Comment: You should also be able to be more specific than "it crashes".  What does that mean?  Infinite loop?  Unhandled exception?  Triple fault?  A decent emulator would show you what's happening.  Do you have a page fault handler at this point, and if so, what does it do?  Again, so many questions that a [mcve] would answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge sorry for not being helpful at times, I'm pretty new here and don't know how to ask questions effectively. So forgive me if it's hard for you to help me when this is the case.

Comment: *upon starting QEMU it instantly closes* - Sounds like you need to look at the terminal you ran QEMU from, if it prints log output there.  Or even attach GDB to QEMU as a remote, so you can single-step the guest.  Or try under Bochs, which has a built-in debugger which "knows about" segmentation and page tables and stuff, and will tell you about faults when they happen.  Trying to develop anything complicated in asm without a debugger makes everything *way* harder and slower than it needs to be, like trying to build a robot blindfolded.

Comment: If I read correctly, you're populating your top-level paging structure (PML4) with 32-bit entries.  But you're going into 64-bit mode; they need to be 64-bit entries, following the format for 64-bit page tables.

Comment: I also don't like the looks of `mov rbp, 0x0007FFFF ;  mov rsp, rbp` which unaligns the stack pointer.  Maybe not the cause of the current crash, but nobody should do that, and compiled C code will be especially unhappy.  It expects odd-multiple-of-8 stack alignment on entry (so align to 16 bytes and then `call KERNEL_LOC` instead of `jmp`.  (The other advantage of `call` is that if your kernel main returns, as it now does, your bootloader gets control back instead of you just returning to whatever garbage address is on the stack.)

Comment: "Emulator instantly closes" sounds like a triple fault, which on a real machine would reboot.  That doesn't narrow it down much, though; you have no IDT and so no exception handlers, so any exception will cause a triple fault.  It's probably either a page fault or a GPF, but at this point we can't tell which.  This is where a good debugging emulator would help (I second the suggestion of Bochs) which will tell you all about the exception as it happens.

Comment: @NateEldredge my kernel doesn't just return to some garbage. Please look [here](https://github.com/teutinsa/UmbrellaOS/blob/master/UmbrellaOS/src/kernel/kernel_entry.asm).

Comment: @NateEldredge I'll try booting my OS in Bochs but I don't have any experience with it. btw I run QEMU with the `-no-reboot` attribute and it just closes but if I leave it out, QEMU just goes into a reboot loop.

Comment: Might want to run it with `-no-reboot -no-shutdown -d int` the `-d int` would show all the interrupts and exceptions that occurred.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I did that and it dumps the CPU registers a couple of times but I have no idea what to get from this.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have no idea why but in the repository `Types.h` is named `types.h` but ist there.

Comment: @NateEldredge please look at the comment I posted under the answer from "git_lk1". some new things have happened that I think you should know of.

Comment: But I think this is one of those things where trying to figure out exactly what little tweaks do or don't make it crash (with locals and without globals, etc) is going to be unhelpful.    You really need to get to a point where you can run it under a debugger and understand what the debugger tells you.  That may require some background study on your part, or practice with simpler programs.

Comment: Oh I see what's going on. When the global variable is added the `.bss` section that will hold the uninitialized `global` variable is at memory address 0x1000 . 0x1000 also happens to be where your paging structures start (your CR3 register points to 0x1000). So you are overwriting your paging structure! You are going to have to move your page structure to somewhere in memory that will not collide with your kernel code and data. Alternately, Maybe you could load your kernel starting at 0x9000 rather than 0x500 (0x9000 is above the paging structure and your memory map as well). A quick hack.

Comment: With your code at 0x500 and `.bss` (uninitialized data including variable `global`) at 0x1000, the failure occurs because the C code starts by setting the variable `global` to 1. `global` is at memory address 0x1000. This overwrites the page structures and creates a bogus virtual address space mapping. It just so happens that bad mapping doesn't map 0x8000 into memory so when you try to access that memory to get the memory map in the C code it throws an exception.

Comment: @NateEldredge : not sure what his intentions were with paging but it does appear it would map the lower 2MiB 1:1 between virtual and physical when seen from 64-bit mode. I'm just not sure if that was by design or luck. Anyway, the issue ends up being that `.bss` with the `global` variable at the start happens to overlap his page structures that start at the same address (0x1000)

Comment: @MichaelPetch that was probably luck. I have now moved my kernel to be loaded at `0x5000` and kept my page structures at  `0x1000` this appears to have fixed the problem. To be honest I completely forgot about my page structures and that I put them at `0x1000`.

Comment: Just be aware that as your kernel grows you will start getting close to 0x7c00 to 0x8000 you run the risk of loading the kernel on top of your bootloader and the sector you loaded at 0x7e00 not to mention 0x8000 where the memory map is. 0x9000 just happens to clear all that stuff that potentially gets in the way again as your kernel expands (and you have to load more sectors into memory)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'll try not to forget although [this](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)) tells me that I should have enough space as long as my kernel does not get larger than 25Kb I should be fine. Should it cause problems I will reorder things in the future. Thanks for both of your help, I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: I'd recommend at a minimum for future debugging purposes you generate an ELF file and then convert it to binary. That way if you want to use QEMU for debug purposes you can sue the ELF file for the debug symbols and data. A slightly modified makefile does that and creates a kernel.dump file with the headers/global data labels/memory locations and dump of the assembly code can be found here:  https://pastebin.com/Xxc2zCz5 . For that to work you need to modify `link.ld` to output 64-bit ELF and that change can be found here:  https://pastebin.com/SWcwaLkc

Comment: Thank you @MichaelPetch, I'll implement that right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I simply forgot that I put my page table structures at `0x1000` and accidentally overrode them when loading my kernel at `0x0500`.
I ended up leaving the structures at `0x1000` and moved my kernel to `0x5000`.

This was a rather simple problem but I would recommend that you still take a look at the comments because there's still a lot of useful information and things to consider.

Answer (score -1):

**First**: *ALWAYS* Initialize variables especially global ones.

**Second**: The problem is surely from your bootloader, can you edit the post to show us how you load your kernel?

Try `objdump` to see if the variable is declared, use -monitor stdio with QEMU and check the value of CR2 Register, it may be a page fault due to the *second* problem.

Here is a solution to check if the variable really has a valid pointer:

You can remove these edits after everything is ok.
instead of :

```
jmp KERNEL_LOC
```

do:

```
call KERNEL_LOC ; RAX Has the pointer of the global variable
jmp $
```

In `kmain` just type:

```
return &global
```

Then run it on QEMU and type in the console `info registers`, RAX should contain the pointer of the variable named `global`.

Comment: after some testing I have come to the conclusion that global variables are not the problem reading EAX (RAX) after having both the address or the value of the global returned in `kmain` has shown the correct results and this code does not cause any problems however if we get to a local variable while there are any globals present the kernel or QEMU or whatever crashes. So I guess the new problem is: "Using locals while also using globals crashes my kernel" or something similar. Yet i have no idea why this is, or how to fix it.

Comment: I got it, your stack pointer is located in the EXTENDED_BIOS_DATA_AREA (0x80000-0x9FFFF) and not in Conventional RAM therefore writing to this area has no effect, local variables are stored in the stack so writing them does not seem to change their values right ? Try putting your stack pointer at conventional memory, 0x110000 for example and tell me if it works. Here is the memory mapping of the low memory (<1MB) https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)

Comment: The EBDA on most systems is 1-4k below 0xa0000 (although it could be much larger, but rarely was). The real issue with the code can be found in the last few comments under the question. It ended up that his kernel's `.bss` section where the `global` variable was placed at the same location as his paging structures at address 0x1000. This caused the virtual memory mapping to be corrupted and future memory accesses could produce an exception/fault. The solution is to put the kernel somewhere where it won't collide with data structures (like page directory/tables etc) he has in the bootloader.

Comment: Yes, he has to create some sort of memory management for that.